# Why my program shortcut is not highlighted in Windows start menu when newly installed?

Tags: c++, windows, nsis

I have a c++ program built with visual studio. An NSIS installer creates a shortcut for the program in the start menu. But the shortcut is not highlighted-as it is the case for all newly installed programs in Windows. [Here](https://nsis.sourceforge.io/Start_Menu_Highlight) it says that I have to add the version resource to my program; Which I did, but still no highlights. Windows 10 x64
Thank you.

Comment: Windows version?

Comment: @Anders Windows 10 64 bit

Comment: Does it appear in the "recently added" start menu section?

Comment: @Anders Yes it does.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think Windows 10 will highlight your new shortcut. If it appears in the "Recently added" section then Windows has correctly detected your new shortcut.

Windows XP to 7 highlighted new shortcuts in a different color. Windows 8 would promote a new shortcut as a tile on the start screen.

Windows 8 and later does some filtering to new shortcuts. Anything that points to a help file, URL or the uninstaller [may be hidden.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190319-00/?p=102342)